# How do you output contents of an array as a comma separated string?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to convert an array if IDs, into a string of comma separated values, to use in a MySQL UPDATE query. How would I do this?

Comment: be very, very careful of SQL injection... if you're building query strings like this, you've probably made a design error.

Comment: i disagree, rmeador. if you know that the contents of the array is safe (eg: all integers), then there's no harm in this style at all.

Comment: @nickf True but I've still run into cases where there wasn't enough type checking on id's. Some extra checking and sanitization is easy and safer in the long run.

Comment: I don't think that there is any question, you can never know what happens, what if you make an error, or if the data is corrupt, or... whatever, ALWAYS sanitize your SQL.

Comment: well yes, you can answer with "sanitise your SQL". You could have just as easily said "check your code into version control", "save often", or "call your mum and tell her you love her"... all of these things are good advice, but are extraneous to the question. :)

Comment: This is only for a maintenance script that will be ran once. Mysql injection is not an issue.

Comment: The fact that it's a maintenance script doesn't guarantee that all values are safe. It's not a matter of deliberate sabotage as much as it's a matter of some values simply not being valid in this context. Besides, quick hacks tend to live longer than first anticipated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remember to escape values:

```
'"' . implode('","', array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data)) . '"'
```

Answer (score 13):

```
implode(',', $array);
```

Comment: just don't forget to check that the array isn't empty first - otherwise your SQL will look like "WHERE `id` IN ()" which is an error.

Comment: This is a dangerous answer given that the stated use of the string is in an SQL statement. See troelskn's answer which demonstrates how you can escape all the array elements.

Comment: We don't know if he didn't get the data already sanitized. But it's true that somebody asking something that simple may need some advices on code security too ;-)

Comment: Read the OP comment. I only answered the question, no need to make needless assumptions

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you pass the results through [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://ca.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) before executing your query. This should prevent sql injection if you use implode() as others suggest.

And as nickf mentions, always check to make sure the array isn't empty or null first, and handle those cases. Since you are only dealing with int's, it wouldn't hurt to put some type checking in your assignments, otherwise you'll get sql errors if a string slips in somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Often this type of situation is people building an array from another table for use in a 2nd query..  If this is the case you can use a subquery to accomplish this.

Eg.
UPDATE Table SET Column = Value WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM Table2 WHERE CONDITIONS )

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better if all ids should be numerical.
Check that it consists of at least one integer with

```
$ids = array_filter($ids, 'is_int');
if (!$ids) {
    //no valid ids returned.
    die('or something');
}
$sql .= '(' . implode(',', $ids) . ')';
```